# insertRowAtIndexes watchKit Swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, watchkit, watchos-2

I have a struct

```
struct Question {
    var title: [String]
    var additionalInfo: String?
    var answers: [String]
}
```

and a variable to which i add the data

```
var questions = [
    Question(title: ["What is the color of?", "additional color information"], additionalInfo: nil, answers: [
        "Blue",
        "Gray"
        ])
]
```

This data loads up in a `tableView` on AppleWatch. Two row types are separated - `TitleRowType` (for titles array) and `AnswersRowType` (for answers array).

When i insert values into `struct's` array - i want to the rows in the `tableView` be inserted with animation.

I know that there's a `insertRowAtIndexes` function, but i cannot wrap my head around it. The example provided in Apple's documentation doesn't work for me. That's what i came up with:

```
    let indexSet = NSIndexSet(index: Int) // Int is passed via the function
    tableView.insertRowsAtIndexes(indexSet, withRowType: "TitleRowType")
```

but when i run it - the table doesn't update.
Looking forward to your advices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do 3 steps:

1. Add the new data to your array
2. Insert a row into the table
3. Populate the row with the new data

Here is a simple example:

```
class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

    @IBOutlet var table: WKInterfaceTable!
    var items = ["row1", "row2", "row3"]

    override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
        super.awakeWithContext(context)
        loadTable()
    }

    func loadTable() {
        table.setNumberOfRows(items.count, withRowType: "tableRow")
        var rowIndex = 0
        for item in items {
            if let row = table.rowControllerAtIndex(rowIndex) as? TableRowController {
                row.label.setText(item)
            }
            rowIndex++
        }
    }

    @IBAction func insertRow() {
        items.append("row4")
        let newIndex = items.count
        table.insertRowsAtIndexes(NSIndexSet(index: newIndex), withRowType: "tableRow")
        if let row = table.rowControllerAtIndex(newIndex) as? TableRowController {
            row.label.setText(items[newIndex])
        }
    }
}
```

`TableRowController` is a `NSObject` subclass that has one `WKInterfaceLabel` outlet to display the number of the row.

I used a button to trigger `insertRow()`

Comment: Thanks! That was very helpful